# How to extend express session timeout

Tags: express, cookies, express-session

I'm using express js 4 together with express-session
and set `maxAge` to one hour. However if user continues accessing the website, the timeout should be extended otherwise the user will be logged out even he/she is still using it.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxx',
  name: 'sessionId',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1*60*60*1000
  })
}))
```

It seems to be a common task but I can't find it anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could solve your problem by increasing `maxAge` each time the user sends a request. When the user sends a request, calculate the time remaining before the session times out, subtract this amount of time from one hour and add the result to `maxAge`. Alternatively you can use the expires property along with a very large maxAge:

```
var hour = 3600000
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour)
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 100 * hour
```

and whenever a request is sent, calculate `expires` again:

```
var hour = 3600000
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour)
```

Comment: Thanks. And should I make this into a middleware and call it within all the routers?

Comment: You are welcome. It makes sense to make sure this is done at a central place, to ease the working process.

Answer (score 28):

`express-session` has a `rolling` property that you can set. By default it's set to `false`. If you set the `rolling` property to `true`, it will reset `expiration` to `maxAge`.

I got the information from the documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#rolling)

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxx',
  name: 'sessionId',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  rolling: true, // <-- Set `rolling` to `true`
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1*60*60*1000
  })
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case only updating the following property worked!
`req.session._expires`

I'm still not entirely sure why ...

I'm using `"express-session": "^1.17.3",`

My code use:

```js
req.session._expires = new Date(Date.now() + (process.env.MAX_SESSION_TIME >> 0))
```